# how can i identify policy renewals by different fields

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, if-statement, where-clause

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhjZ0.jpg)What I am trying to do is count the number of renewals with the different sales trees.

In the case of NumberPlate "015ABN", the customer always renews with the same "company" twice renews with "boss 2", but renews with different "sellers" (seller1, seller2)

this is what i tried

data ['renewal'] = (np.where (data.NumberPlate == data.NumberPlate.shift (), 1, np.nan))
This information tells me that there was a renovation that works for me when I only compare two years but I don't know how to take into account the fields of sales trees.

The other problem I have has complicated me a bit is the difference in the dates on which they are renewed. In subtraction, I use it with a data ['difference'] = (np.where (data.NumberPlate == data.NumberPlate.shift (), data.Expedition_Date.diff (), np.nan))

This creates a field with the difference of days but returns the value of "366 days 04: 01: 19.177000000" but I have to subtract a year to be displayed in days. I must subtract 365 days.

I present three different cases each registration. Some customers are loyal to renew with the company, other customers renew with the boss and other customers renew with the seller.

I appreciate if you can help me with this

```
seller  sellers_boss    Company NumberPlate Expedition_Date effective_date  year    difference  renewal_Company Renewal_sellers_boss    Renewal_seller
Seller  1   Boss  1 Global Company_1    015ABN  2015-05-14 08:37:48.000 2015-05-15 08:37:48.000 2015    0   1   1   1
Seller  1   Boss  2 Global Company_1    015ABN  2016-05-13 12:39:07.177 2016-05-15 08:37:48.000 2016    2   2   1   1
Seller  2   Boss  2 Global Company_1    015ABN  2017-05-12 17:01:39.900 2017-05-15 08:37:48.000 2017    3   3   2   1
Seller 1    Boss  1 Global Company_1    016ZYX  2015-05-15 08:37:48.000 2015-05-15 08:37:48.000 2014    0   1   1   1
Seller 1    Boss  1 Global Company_1    016ZYX  2016-05-12 12:39:07.177 2016-05-15 12:39:07.177 2015    3   2   2   2
Seller 1    Boss  1 Global Company_1    016ZYX  2017-05-11 17:01:39.900 2017-05-15 17:01:39.900 2016    4   3   3   3
Seller 1    Boss  1 Global Company_1    016ZYX  2018-05-14 17:01:39.900 2018-05-15 17:01:39.900 2017    1   4   4   4
Seller 1    Boss  1 Global Company_1    016ZYX  2019-05-15 17:01:39.900 2019-05-15 17:01:39.900 2018    0   5   5   5
Seller 1    Boss  1 Global Company_1    025ABC  2015-05-15 08:37:48.000 2015-05-15 08:37:48.000 2014    0   1   1   1
Seller 1    Boss  1 Global Company_1    025ABC  2016-05-13 12:39:07.177 2016-05-15 12:39:07.177 2015    2   2   2   2
Seller 2    Boss  1 Global Company_1    025ABC  2017-05-10 17:01:39.900 2017-05-15 17:01:39.900 2016    5   3   3   1
Seller 1    Boss  1 Global Company_2    025ABC  2018-05-14 17:01:39.900 2018-05-15 17:01:39.900 2017    4   1   1   1
Seller 1    Boss  1 Global Company_2    025ABC  2019-05-15 17:01:39.900 2019-05-15 17:01:39.900 2018    0   2   2   2
```

Comment: You need to format your question. Almost impossible to understand the data. Use control k to format code and data

Comment: r=data.groupby(['Company'])['NumberPlate'].apply(lambda x : x.ne(x.shift()).ne(0).cumsum())
data['Renewal_Company']=data.groupby([data.Company,r]).cumcount()+1 this code works for this option

Comment: s=data.groupby(['Company','sellers_boss'])['NumberPlate'].apply(lambda x : x.ne(x.shift()).ne(0).cumsum())
data['Renewal_sellers_boss']=data.groupby([data['sellers_boss'],s]).cumcount()+1          for this option it doesn't work

Comment: k=data.groupby(['Company','sellers_boss','seller'])['NumberPlate'].apply(lambda x : x.ne(x.shift()).ne(0).cumsum())
data['Renewal_seller']=data.groupby([data['seller'],k]).cumcount()+1        for this option it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
s=data.groupby(['Company'])['NumberPlate'].apply(lambda x : x.ne(x.shift()).ne(0).cumsum())
data['Renewal_Company']=data.groupby([data.Company,s]).cumcount()+1
```

next level

```
d=data.groupby(['Company','sellers_boss'])['NumberPlate'].apply(lambda x : x.ne(x.shift()).ne(0).cumsum())
data['Renewal_seller_boss']=data.groupby([data.sellers_boss,data.Company,d]).cumcount()+1
```

next level

```
q=data.groupby(['Company','sellers_boss','seller'])['NumberPlate'].apply(lambda x : x.ne(x.shift()).ne(0).cumsum())
data['Renewal_seller']=data.groupby([data.Company,data.sellers_boss,data.seller,q]).cumcount()+1
```